# How to get all additional attributes of Magento Product without explicitly specifying them

Tags: java, php, soap, magento, axis

My goal is to get and display all additional attributes for the Magento product using SOAP API. For example Gender, Shirt Size and Color for T-Shirt product. But the program shouldn't know the attribute names.

In the SOAP Call: catalogProductInfo there is additional attributes parameter and it looks like I have to explicitly specify additional attribute names.

I am using Java and Apache Axis to connect to Mangeto SOAP API and the code is following:

```
stub.catalogProductInfo(sessionId, "118", null, null);

call declaration:
public com.magentocommerce.api.CatalogProductReturnEntity catalogProductInfo(java.lang.String sessionId, java.lang.String productId, java.lang.String storeView, com.magentocommerce.api.CatalogProductRequestAttributes attributes) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {

attributes parameter constructor declaration:
public CatalogProductRequestAttributes(
       java.lang.String[] attributes,
       java.lang.String[] additional_attributes) {
```

But I have to specify last parameter somehow to get all additional attributes.
Is it possible to do through SOAP API?

**Update**: "*" as attribute doesn't work

```
CatalogProductRequestAttributes attrs = new CatalogProductRequestAttributes();
attrs.setAttributes(new String[] {"*"});
attrs.setAdditional_attributes(new String[] {"*"});
```

Resulted object is not filled neither with standard attributes nor with additional attributes.

Comment: Hi! I also tried to get those additional attributes via soapUI by sending either the attribute-id or the attribute-label. It didn't work at all!?

Comment: Any updates? I am also facing this problem and currently looking for the simplest solution. If there isn't any the only workaround will be overriding API implementation.

Comment: Didn't put my hands on this anymore. You have to find a workaround for yourself as I did.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried through the API specifically, but have you tried specifying `*` as the attribute name? That's how it's done in the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to call the API for the list of additional attributes:
catalogProductListOfAdditionalAttributes

Then loop through the results and construct your second request to specific product.